# How to make the mean, standard deviation and mode statistics of an NxN matrix

Tags: python, matrix, statistics, mean, standard-deviation

I would like to know how to do the average, standard deviation and mode statistics of an NxN matrix.

Can anybody suggest how to do this in python?

Comment: Before asking others for help on something as simple as this, you can do a google search for keywords such as "python numpy array mean standard deviation mode statistics".  What results do you get?  Click the links and find the relevant methods/functions, then try writing some code.

Comment: If you're still struggling, here's a link to the main statistics methods for numpy arrays https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.statistics.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get the mode by counting occurrences and returning the max.
Average is the sum divided by the count.
For stddev you can sum the squared distances, divide that by the count minus 1, and take the square root.

```
#! /usr/env python

import math

matrix = []
for i in range(9):
    matrix.append([])
    for x in range(9):
        matrix[i].append(i+x*2)

mode = {}
avg = 0
stddev = 0
count = 0
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for x in range(len(matrix[i])):
        avg+=matrix[i][x]
        if matrix[i][x] in mode:
            mode[matrix[i][x]]+=1
        else:
            mode[matrix[i][x]]=1
        count+=1
maxcount = max(mode,key=mode.get)
avg /= count
# if you calculate the count from the dimensions...
# avg /= len(matrix)*len(matrix[0])
print(f'Mode = {maxcount} with {mode[maxcount]} occurrences')
print(f'Avg = {avg}')

# get the std dev
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for x in range(len(matrix[i])):
        stddev += (matrix[i][x]-avg) ** 2
stddev /= count-1
print(f'Stddev = {math.sqrt(stddev)}')
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in a comment,  this is easily found by a search.

The **scipy** library offers functions for all of these, either for the whole array or for specified axes. **scipy.stats.describe** will give the mean and variance all at once, and standard deviation is easily computed from variance. For mode use **scipy.stats.mode**

Alternatively for mean and standard deviation, there are **numpy.mean** and **numpy.std** respectively.